# Wrap std shared pointer using Shiboken 2

Tags: c++, python-3.x, wrapper, pyside2

How to wrap C++ *std*'s *shared pointer* (`std::shared_ptr`) using Shiboken 2?

I know that there is Qt's shared pointer `QSharedPointer` and it can be used by adding a line in a **.xml** typesystem file:

```
<smart-pointer-type name="QSharedPointer" type="shared" getter="data" />
```

However I need `std::shared_ptr` and therefore tried something similar, example given:

```
<smart-pointer-type name="std::shared_ptr" type="shared" getter="get" />
```

Notice that there is **get** as **getter** instead of **data**.

Comment: Your question is very confused. Whst *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Thanks for the comment. I want to find a way to wrap C++'s `shared_ptr` and use it in Python.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I had faced. I ended up patching shiboken source code.
Checkout my fork on github https://github.com/raccoonmonk/pyside2 branch 'shared_ptr'; literally couple of commits. It's way behind from the current state though. At that time I've been told that std::shared_ptr support is beyond of pyside2 project priorities.